# ng-grid won’t scroll to last row

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Using ng-grid I want to show a newly added row by scrolling to it when it is added to the bottom of the list.

please see the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/4jgy9wwr2HRhfhgKMKcX?p=preview

```
var grid = $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid;
grid.$viewport.scrollTop((($scope.myData.length - 1)* grid.config.rowHeight));
```

I don’t understand why the grid won’t scroll all the way down. I tried adding the rowHeight ever subtracting it but every time the grid just will not scroll to the very last row.

I know by adding the records to the top of the list will solve the problem by I am sorting the grid and by its nature the empty record will be pushed to the bottom.

Comment: works when you add a timeout, see http://plnkr.co/edit/9AQzp3D6B4l95xdTxwf9

Comment: As a side issue you're adding a new listener every time you add a new item to the list.  You really only need or want one listener.   The return value of `on` is a function that terminates the listener.  So an easy way to ensure you only instantiate one is to assign your '$scope.$on' to a variable (e = $scope.$on(...)).  Then call e (`e();`) at the end of `on` terminating the listener.

Comment: @KayakDave thanks for explaining that! Was thinking some scary recursion was going on! =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You dont need the "ngGridEventData", and if you log it you will notice he is fired for each existing row on your grid, wich is not optimal.

As already answered, you can use the $timeout service whith a 0 delay. It sounds a bit tricky, and it's maybe not a best practice but it works.

Load it in your controller :

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    //load
}
```

Then in your addNew() :

```
$scope.addNew = function () {

    $scope.myData.push({ name: "new", age: 100 });

    $timeout(function () {
        var grid = $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid;
        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem($scope.myData.length - 1, true);
        grid.$viewport.scrollTop((($scope.myData.length - 1) * grid.config.rowHeight));
    }, 0);

};
```

Check the result here : http://plnkr.co/edit/4HNqFh7uu9IWCjDVt5WR?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Actually Bug lies in ng-grid js file to calculate correct scrolling offset. 
Please follow link
http://pushkarkinikar.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/ng-grid-scrolling-issue/

where 
I have explained it in detail